# How do I export a target, then use it in another project via ExternalProject?

Tags: build, cmake, buildconfiguration, external-project

I have a CMake project named `proj1`, which I want to use as an external project in another project, `proj2`. Now, the (relevant) command in `proj1`'s `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
install(
    TARGETS proj1
    ARCHIVE
    DESTINATION lib
    EXPORT proj1_library
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
    CONFIGURATIONS Release RelWithDebugInfo
)
```

and I want to use this static library in `proj2`, without explicitly "guessing" where it's installed to be `proj1`. I want to be able to get obtain this target from `proj1` (which I obtain using `ExternalProject`), then use it - directly or indirectly - in `add_target_libraries()` commands.

How should I do that? And - do I only need to make changes to `proj2` or also to `proj1`'s `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting the targets is the right approach.

To support this, `proj1` would have to generate a `proj1Config.cmake` in both its build tree and also in the install tree (so that a development package for `proj1` can be used as a SDK [1])

I suggest you read the following section of the CMake documentation, it covers the different concepts and provides an example. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages

[1] SDK: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit

Comment: Thank you, but - in SO answers it's customary to provide an in-place answer rather than a link. Can you descirbe how such a `.cmake` file is to be generated and used? Or at least give an example?